# How to create a 3rd Ad push in a custom Omega Kickstart subtheme

Tags: blocks, advertising

I'm using drupal commerce kickstart 7x to design an experimental website to understand the layout & methods of the CMS.

I've just started using Drupal. To be precise, 3 days. This is very new to me.

I want to know how does one go about placing a 3rd Ad Push block in the "Postscript third" section. I've sub themed Omega kickstart.

I've tried creating blocks, editing the fields, editing views, reordering the blocks and contents. Yet none seem to work.

I can only create a block with text as its body. But what I want to achieve is a 3rd block with an image in it just like the preceding 2 AD Push blocks.

How do I do it?

Images for reference:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to Site settings->Visual & Layout -> Views. You will see the View for Ad push blocks. Click on Edit for this View. Clone the Second ad push block. Be sure to:

- change the name to Third ad push block
- set the Pager to 1 item, skip 2
- save changes

Go to Site settings->Visual & Layout -> Blocks and add the Third ad push block to the Postscript Third Region and click Save blocks.

Reload your page and the block should be visible on the front page.